# Leaving airport during a layover

Tags: transit, layovers, transit-visas, algerian-citizens

Is it OK to leave an airport while in transit?

I am from Algeria and am going to fly to Turkey with a 14-hour layover in Amsterdam. Can I leave the airport without issues?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. As an Algerian, to enter the Netherlands you need a Schengen visa (type C), which you apply for at the [embassy of the Netherlands in Algiers](http://alger.nlambassade.org/)